# Precisions about incron event

Tags: linux, debian, incron

I'm currently learning a little bit the incron. To learn I have a working incron on a VM, watching when a file is moved into a watched folder.

Here is the incron :

```
/var/share/entrant/DEFAULT/ IN_CLOSE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE /opt/maarch/separateur_qr/scripts/incron.sh $@$#
```

So it use the `IN_CLOSE, IN_CLOSE_WRITE, IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE` event. But after read the incron doc, I see the `IN_MOVE_TO` event.

Why it works with this 3 events ? For me it's brainfuck, because I don't think the file is opened when moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the file is opened or not when moved depends on the target location:

When the target location is on the same filesystem as the original location, `mv` will just use the `rename` syscall an do *not* open the file.

When the target location is on a different filesystem, `mv` will open the file, copy it using `read` / `write` system calls and finally remove the original file.